# how to find a data from a table and validate with text if its match confirm data is exist

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

A table has a column "Code" and trying to match from access form text box if the data in the textbox match with data in column "Code" it has to say yes data is exist.. request your kind assistance.i tried but seems to be wrong

```
ecode = Me.code.Text
Dim dupsql

dupsql = "SELECT Code FROM [BookingTable]WHERE Code ='" & ecode & "'"
'Debug.Print dupsql
If dupsql = ecode Then

MsgBox " The Entered Code is already in Use! ", vbInformation
end if
```

Comment: trying use Dlookup,   Dim datafind As String
datafind = DLookup("Code", "BookingTable")
'Debug.Print datafind

If datafind = ecode Then
MsgBox " The Entered Code is already in Use! ", vbInformation
End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SELECT SQL statement is used to open a recordset object. Your code does not open a recordset object. Just referencing variable that holds SQL string does nothing.

Don't need a recordset object. DLookup domain aggregate function can serve.

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("Code", "BookingTable", "Code='" & Me.Code & "'") Then
    MsgBox " The Entered Code is already in Use! ", vbInformation
End If
```

Or DCount.

```
If DCount("*", "BookingTable", "Code='" & Me.Code & "'") > 0 Then
```

Comment: thanks for your guidens .. as per your past question you suggested to use Dlookup and i tried that worked .. .thank you lot

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code and it works.

```vb
ecode = Me.code.Text
Dim datafind As String
datafind = Nz(DLookup("[Code]", "BookingTable", "Code = '" & ecode & "'"), 0)
Debug.Print datafind

If datafind = ecode Then
MsgBox " The Entered Code is already in Use! ", vbInformation
end if
```